# Как сделать так чтобы за раз бот принимал несколько песен и сохранял их в плейлист?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, telebot, аудио, python-telegram-bot

Пытаюсь сделать телеграм бота для музыкальных плейлистов на питоне pytelegrambotapi.
Как сделать так чтобы за раз бот принимал несколько песен и сохранял их в плейлист?
У меня пока получается принимать их только по одному

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['addtoplaylist'])
def cmd_add_song_to_playlist(message: Message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, f"choose playlist to add song:",
                        reply_markup=generate_list_of_playlists_buttons(chat_id))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, check_choose_playlist_to_add_song)


def check_choose_playlist_to_add_song(message: Message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    playlist_name = message.text
    msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, f"send song to add to playlist",
                        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, check_add_song_to_playlist, playlist_name)


def check_add_song_to_playlist(message: Message, playlist_name):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    song_unique_id = message.audio.file_id
    database = sqlite3.connect("tg_bot_project.db")
    cursor = database.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO all_songs(song_unique_id, playlist_name, telegram_id)
            VALUES(?,?,?)
        """, (song_unique_id, playlist_name, chat_id))

    database.commit()
    database.close()
    bot.send_message(chat_id, f'your song successfully added to playlist <b>«<i>{playlist_name}</i>»</b>!')
```